# can return java stream groupingby to this's array variable?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

Q.1)
hi, java stream's groupingby can make oneself's array varible?

this is entity

```
public class Test {
   private int id;
   private int itemId;
   private int[] itemIds;
   private boolean filter;
}
```

this is test List sample

```
{
   test(id=1, itemId=1)
   test(id=1, itemId=2)
   test(id=1, itemId=3)
   test(id=2, itemId=5)
   test(id=2, itemId=11)
}
```

And i want group by test.id, for example

```
{
   test(id=1, itemIds=[1,2,3])
   test(id=2, itemIds=[5,11])
}
```

what should i do?

```
tests.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId), ?, ?);
```

Q.2) how can i merge bellow two stream codes?

```
tests.stream().filter(Test::isFilter).anyMatch(t -> {throw new Exception;});
```

```
tests.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId, ?, ?); // Q1 result
```

about this..?

```
tests.stream().filter(Test::isFilter).anyMatch(t -> {throw new Exception;}).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId, ?, ?);
```

Q3) above Q1, Q2's stream codes are better performance than java 'for' syntax?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: For Q1, you could simply do ```tests.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId));```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grouping assuming a constructor like `Test(int id, int itemId, int[] itemIds)` and fluent getters such as `id()`, `itemId()` and `itemIds()` you could unflatten your data this way:

```java
List<Test> unflattenedTests = tests.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::id))
   .entrySet().stream().map(e -> new Test(
       e.getKey().intValue(),
       0,
       e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Test::itemId).toArray()
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As for merging your filter & throwing logic within a single statement I can't really think of any other way than `peek` such as:

```java
List<Test> unflattenedTests = tests.stream()
   .peek(t -> { if (t.isFilter()) throw new RuntimeException(); })
   .collect(...
```

Answer (score 0):

**@plalx** thanks for answer!

Thanks to answer, this is my solution

```
tests.stream()
    .peek(t -> {if (Test::isFilter) throw new Exception();})
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getId, Collectors.mapping(Test::getItemId, Collectors.toSet())))
    .forEach((id, itemIdSet) -> {
        if (!somBusiness(id, itemIdSet)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    };
```

what do you think, my solution.
i worry about low performance.

Anyway, my knowledge has been upgraded!
thanks a lot. :)